# Agda: Could not parse the application

Tags: agda

when I try to load  this example from the **Programming Language Foundations in Agda** it fails:

```
module Test where
import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq using (_≡_; refl)
open Eq.≡-Reasoning using (begin_; _∎; _≡⟨⟩_)

data Nat : Set where
    zero : Nat
    suc : Nat → Nat

{-# BUILTIN NATURAL Nat #-}

_+_ : Nat → Nat → Nat
(suc m) + n  = suc (m + n)
zero + n = n

_ : 2 + 3 ≡ 5
_ =
  begin
    2 + 3
  ≡⟨⟩    -- is shorthand for
    (suc (suc zero)) + (suc (suc (suc zero)))
  ≡⟨⟩    -- inductive case
    suc ((suc zero) + (suc (suc (suc zero))))
  ≡⟨⟩    -- inductive case
    suc (suc (zero + (suc (suc (suc zero)))))
  ≡⟨⟩    -- base case
    suc (suc (suc (suc (suc zero))))
  ≡⟨⟩    -- is longhand for
    5
  ∎
```

First warning:

```
warning: -W[no]ModuleDoesntExport
The module Eq.≡-Reasoning doesn't export the following:
  _≡⟨⟩_
when scope checking the declaration
  open Eq.≡-Reasoning using (begin_; _∎; _≡⟨⟩_)
```

Second error:

```
Could not parse the application
begin 2 + 3 ≡ (suc (suc zero)) + (suc (suc (suc zero))) ≡ suc
((suc zero) + (suc (suc (suc zero)))) ≡ suc
(suc (zero + (suc (suc (suc zero))))) ≡ suc
(suc (suc (suc (suc zero)))) ≡ 5 ∎
Operators used in the grammar:
  +     (infix operator, level 20)  [_+_ (C:\Users\user\Documents\Agda\VSC\Test.agda:12,1-4)]                                                                            
  ∎     (postfix operator, level 3) [_∎ (C:\cabal\agda-stdlib-2.0\src\Relation\Binary\Reasoning\Syntax.agda:442,3-5)]                                                     
  ≡     (infix operator, level 4)   [_≡_ (C:\cabal\store\ghc-9.4.8\Agda-2.6.4.1-e51cf1324caf3a56d7db642f01cda06d05fc0698\share\lib\prim\Agda\Builtin\Equality.agda:6,6-9)]
  begin (prefix operator, level 1)  [begin_ (C:\cabal\agda-stdlib-2.0\src\Relation\Binary\Reasoning\Syntax.agda:51,3-9)]                                                  
when scope checking
begin 2 + 3 ≡ (suc (suc zero)) + (suc (suc (suc zero))) ≡ suc
((suc zero) + (suc (suc (suc zero)))) ≡ suc
(suc (zero + (suc (suc (suc zero))))) ≡ suc
(suc (suc (suc (suc zero)))) ≡ 5 ∎
```

I'm using Agda standard library 2.0 and I noticed the operator ***≡⟨⟩*** is not in **[Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/v2.0/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.Core.html)** anymore ([compared with 1.7.2](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/v1.7.2/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.Core.html)), but I couldn't find any replacement. Also I'm not sure what the operator "*≡⟨⟩*" means or hoagw can it be replaced, but also I'm not sure if that's actually the reason why it fails to load.

Comment: If you rename `≡⟨⟩` to `≈⟨⟩`, will it type check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is an issue with standard lib v2.0](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/issues/2298):

> I just looked into this. The underlying issue isn't that *≡⟨⟩* has
> been removed, but that it's now declared as a syntax for a different
> name, which breaks opening the ≡-Reasoning module with only some names
> as PLFA instructs. I agree this is unfortunate.
>
> In the meantime, you can replace open Eq.≡-Reasoning using (begin_;
> *≡⟨⟩*; *∎) with open Eq.≡-Reasoning using (begin*; step-≡-∣; _∎). The convention in stdlib is to not use a using clause on the various
> Reasoning modules, which is why we hadn't noticed until now.

The solution is to use standard lib 1.7.3 or wait for a fix.